# CoreData fault and data not read when I need them

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios4

I need to pass an object managed by CoreData to a view, so I create a property of the same type in the descendant of UITableViewController class this way:

```
@property (strong) Event *udalostTermin;
```

in @interface and

```
@synthesize udalostTermin;
```

in @implementation and fill this property just before pushViewController:animated: of the view is called.

When in viewDidLoad, everything is still OK, print says:

```
<Event: 0x868c160> (entity: Event; id: 0x8684220 
    <x-coredata:///Event/t22D3C10C-1BFC-40DE-918F-0E12A5473CA03> ; data: {
createDate = "2012-06-29 11:21:37 +0000";
doctor = nil;
end = "2012-06-29 11:21:37 +0000";
```

and so on. But when the app runs into tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: where I need to display the data, print of the object says:

```
<Event: 0x868c160> (entity: Event; id: 0x8684220 
    <x-coredata:///Event/t22D3C10C-1BFC-40DE-918F-0E12A5473CA03> ; data: <fault>)
```

without explicitly doing anything with the object before and the object thus gives me wrong, empty data. What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: There are two different things here: an object turning into a fault and wrong data.  Even if it is a fault, it should still get the right data when you ask for it.  What do you see when you try to access properties of the `Event`?  (Also, you may be able to create a `didTurnIntoFault` method in `Event` and put a breakpoint there to see why it's being called.)

Comment: In viewDidLoad, `po [udalostTermin createDate]` gives
`(id) $2 = 0x08647be0 2012-06-29 12:28:06 +0000`. In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: it gives `(id) $3 = 0x00000000 <nil>`. When the app stops in didTurnIntoFault:, NSLog: called on self prints `<Event: 0x807ff60> (entity: Event; id: 0x805bc00 <x-coredata://6C8D076F-BC40-4DB0-894F-BD5175E1EE33/Event/p1> ; data: {
    createDate = nil;
    doctor = nil;
    end = nil;`
etc.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas.  :)  In `didTurnIntoFault`, if you put `NSLog(@"didTurnIntoFault: %@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);`, does it give any hints about why it's being called?

Comment: It prints (shortened):
    0   -[Event didTurnIntoFault] + 51
    1   -[NSFaultHandler turnObject:intoFaultWithContext:] + 555
    2   -[NSManagedObjectContext reset] + 803
    3   -[UIUdalostDetail viewWillDisappear:] + 505
`UIUdalostDetail` is the "old" view which is making place for the new one. Probably `NSManagedObjectContext reset` destroys the data -- but I want to use them even in the new view. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it sounds as if the answer is to **not** call `reset` on your `NSManagedObjectContext`  From the documentation for `reset`: 'All the receiver's managed objects are “forgotten.”'  ...which basically means invalid in memory.